# What is this 4x1 pin connector that connects my SD card drive to my motherboard

Tags: motherboard, computer-building

Recently, I decided to upgrade an old HP Pavillon computer that we bought ten years ago with a new motherboard, CPU and RAM. Although the RAM has not yet arrived, I connected all the cables to their associated header and I was able to connect all the cables but one. This is the cable:

[image: connectors]

The black connector leads to the SD card reader on the front panel of the case. The white connector used to lead to the old motherboard, but unfortunately, while disassembling, I lost track of where. Does anyone know where I would stick the white 4x1 connector please, and what it is called?

Comment: It is almost certainly a low quality internal USB cable.

Comment: Would it stick in a USB header like a normal cable? If so which side do i stick it on

Comment: Your motherboard will have a set of pins much like https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyNEB.png . That connector would simply slip on to those pins. Your motherboard manual should tell you where the header is and what pin is what. Red is *usually* +5V, black is GND and the +/- would be the other two.

Comment: That white *"4x1 connector"* is actually a 5x1.  If you look closely, the fifth position (on one end) is blocked off, i.e. it's a key to indicate orientation.  You need to look for a 5x1 header (on the motheboard) with one post cut off.

Answer (score 0):

This is a USB cable and it plugs into the motherboard. Since I can't see a picture of the motherboard you will need to contact the manufacturer for additional support.

Answer (score -1):

Since there are no pictures of the motherboard, I can't tell if your motherboard has any dedicated or available pins for that kind of front panel readers.

However, you can usually plug these 4-pin front reader ports (that usually are similar in function to usb) in the 4-pin lower row of any of the front USB (JUSB1/2/3) pins of the motherboard. Now, you want to make sure that the red cable is on the left side (it usually comes with an additional 4+1 blank slot so that you can't make that mistake).

Here is a video that sums it up pretty well;
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kNxaAs5Ml4

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1179547)